# A vector is created inside an if block in Rust. How to use it after the scope of if ends?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, rust, ownership

I am learning Rust. I am trying to calculate a list of prime numbers up to some number. For that I need to create a vector (`vec1`) inside an `if` block and use it outside the scope of the `if`.

I tried a code with the same logic in MATLAB and it works.

A simplified version of the actual code looks like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut initiate = 1;
    let mut whilechecker = 2;

    while whilechecker > 0 {
        whilechecker = whilechecker - 1;

        if initiate == 1 {
            let mut vec1 = vec![2];
        }

        for i in &vec1 {
            if *i == 2 {
                break;
            }
        } //for

        initiate = 2;
        vec1.push(5);
    } //while
} //main
```

It is supposed to put a list of prime numbers in `vec1`. But since it is simplified code it should compile and giving a vector (vec1) will suffice.
But the compiler says:

> cannot find value `vec1` in this scope

at `for i in  &vec1{` and at `vec1.push(5);`.

Can you make it compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to have the complicated `if initialize==1` checking. Just move the initialization of the vector outside the while loop, so it gets done only once:

```
fn main() {
    let mut whilechecker = 2;

    let mut vec1 = vec![2];
    while whilechecker > 0 {
        whilechecker = whilechecker - 1;
        for i in &vec1 {
            if *i == 2 {
                break;
            }
        } //for

        vec1.push(5);
    } //while
} //main
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Around 6 times faster than MATLAB after release. But say in case we need to create a vector inside an if block and use it outside the scope of the if. How do you do that?   In another approach to find primes I needed to create a vector and use it before for loop, use it inside the for loop, and use it again outside the for loop. let mut vec1=vec![4,5];  vec1.push(6);  for i in 1..4 {vec1.push(6);}  vec1.push(7);

Comment: If there is some condition inside for loop that limits the vector from expanding infinitely.  How do we make the above code compile?

Comment: @Pandharinath It's not really clear what you mean, I would advice you to make a new question about that.

Answer (score -2):

I don't get the thing which you actually want. But here is an example which may help you to define the global scope variable.

```
fn main() {
    let mut initiate = 1;
    let mut whilechecker = 2;
    let mut vec1 = Vec::new();

    while whilechecker > 0 {
        if initiate == 1 {
            let mut vec1 = vec![2];
        }

        for i in &vec1 {
            if *i == 2 {
                break;
            }
        }

        initiate = 2;
        vec1.push(5);
        whilechecker = whilechecker - 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", vec1);
}
```

The output of the given code is:

```
[5, 5]
```

Comment: You probably meant to change `let mut vec1 = ...` to just `vec1 = ...` inside the `if`; otherwise you just shadow the outer variable (rustc gives two warnings, about `vec1` being unnecessarily `mut` and about it being unused).